# Why it doesn't draw the exponential curve in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm learning the basics of javascript at school, now I'm working on the canvas

**This is my code**

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
offset = canvas.width / 2

function assi() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(offset, 0)
  ctx.lineTo(offset, offset * 2)
  ctx.moveTo(0, offset)
  ctx.lineTo(offset * 2, offset)
  ctx.stroke()
}

function f(x) {
  return Math.pow(2, x) * -1;
}

function draw() {
  assi()
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

  moveTo(offset, f(0) + offset)
  for (let x = -offset; x < offset; x++) {
    ctx.lineTo(x + offset, f(x) + offset)
  }
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw()">
  <canvas height="800" width="800" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**This is my question**
why in the function `f(x)` if I leave `*-1` it doesn't draw anything, while if I delete `*-1` it draws something?

It draws linear functions, but the exponential function gives problem, and is not `Math.pow()` the problem, because if I use 1 as base it works (actually draws a line, but is right)

*The `*-1` is needed to mirror the y-axis of canvas axis system (up to down) into cartesian axis system (down to up)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like drawing lines to very high negative numbers causes problems...

If you want that code to show something useful, we can add an if statement for those with positive Y values, we could also restrict to a not so big negative, but I leave that up to you.
I'm drawing arcs to show the points and also divide the output of the function to lower the amount, showing different curves.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
const offset = canvas.width / 2

function f(x) {
  return Math.pow(2, x) * -1;
}

let colors = ["black","cyan", "red", "blue", "green", "pink"]
for (let i = 1; i <= colors.length; i++) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = colors[i-1]
  for (let x = -offset; x < offset; x++) {
    let y = f(x/i) + offset + i*10
    if (y > 0) {
      ctx.arc(x + offset, y, 1, 0, 6)
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<canvas height="200" width="200" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

---

Here is your entire code:

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
offset = canvas.width / 2

function assi() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(offset, 0)
  ctx.lineTo(offset, offset * 2)
  ctx.moveTo(0, offset)
  ctx.lineTo(offset * 2, offset)
  ctx.stroke()
}

function f(x) {
  return Math.pow(2, x) * -1;
}

function draw() {
  assi()
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red"

  moveTo(offset, f(0) + offset)
  for (let x = -offset; x < offset; x++) {
    let y = f(x) + offset
    if (y > -1000) {
      ctx.lineTo(x + offset, y)
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw()">
  <canvas height="200" width="200" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```